# Certain Unicode Characters not displaying when setting text to TextButton in libgdx

Tags: 2d, libgdx, fonts, text

Ok I am trying to do a word game much like Hangman Pro but for a different language(specifically amharic) using `libgdx` . And I have got a list of words saved to text file and I have taken care of `BOM` problem when reading the file. Problem arises when setting the individual characters from a random word to a `TextButton`.

Here is a snapshot of the problem:

[image]

The part I marked red are the ones missing and it is the same word in both cases. And I know the word is correctly being read because it outputs correctly on `console`

Here is init code and console output

```
public void init(){
        char [] indiv = WordList.randomWord.toCharArray();
        int index = 0;
        Skin skinCanyonBunny = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal(Constants.SKIN_WORDGAME_UI),
                new TextureAtlas(Constants.TEXTURE_ATLAS_UI));
        String name = "textb-dn";
        TextButtonStyle tbs = new TextButtonStyle(skinCanyonBunny.getDrawable("textb-up"),
                skinCanyonBunny.getDrawable("textb-dn"),
                skinCanyonBunny.getDrawable("textb-checked"),
                Assets.instance.assetFonts.defaultNormal);
        for(int i =0;i<Constants.WORD_TABLE_SIZE;i++){
            String tempText = String.valueOf(indiv[(index++)%indiv.length]);
            TextButton temp = new TextButton(tempText, skinLibgdx);
            btnPlayArray.add(temp);
        }

        for(int i = 0;i<Constants.WORD_TABLE_SIZE;i++){
            btnPlayArray.get(i).addListener(new TestInputtListenerOverflow(btnPlayArray.get(i).hashCode()));
        }

    }
```

And a sample of console output. the last one is the random selected word.

```
entry: ቴክኖሎጂ 5
entry: ኢንዱስትሪ 6
entry: ሀይል 3
entry: ወደፊት 4
entry: አቅጣጫዎች 6
entry: ሰው 2
com.tamirat.wordgame.WordGame: ኢንዱስትሪ
```

Can anyone tell me what is happening? If it helps I am using Nyala `ttf` font and converting them to `bitmap` using `Font Forge`. Alternatively I use `BMFont`. Thanks

Comment: Is the missing character present in the bitmap generated by Font Forge?

Comment: doesn't seem to be on the images. anything to do abt it?

Comment: Try using Hiero (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Hiero), and see if that renders the characters you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working now using `hiero` runnable `jar`. I had to add every character manually. Not an easy task since there are over 180 distinct characters in the alphabet and resources don't come easy for this particular case. I wish there were less complicated tools for board games like this.Thanks for the help @bornander.

Comment: Cool. Glad I could help. Consider using the libGDX FreeType extension, it will allow you to create the bitmap at runtime and that means you can optimise them for the screen size better.

Comment: yeah tried it. that was a no go too. this is a peculiar case.